# How to count repetitions of each record in a query having multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which uses MULTIPLE tables and joins. It returns a list of items. I need to count how many times each item appears in that list. I'm working on Oracle database using SQL Developer.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]. You can improve your question by posting the table structure, some sample data, desired result and what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP, [example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-jan/o13sql-1886636.html):

```
select COUNT(employee_id), department_id
      from employee
    GROUP BY department_id
    ORDER BY department_id;
```

Result:

```
COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID)  DEPARTMENT_ID
——————————————————  —————————————
                 6             10
                 2             20
                 2             30
                 1
```

Comment: This returns the Count based on other table joins maybe. I need the count as I see from my query output.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this one?

```
Select COUNT(e.employee_id), d.dept_name
from employee    e
inner department   d
  on d.id = e.dept_id
GROUP BY d.dept_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see your query to understand better your issue and find an accurate solution, but if you use the count function like this, you have the list of repeated elements with a counter column:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Quantity", l1.attrib, l2.attrib
  FROM list1 l1, list2 l2
  WHERE l1.attrib = l2.attrib
  GROUP BY l1.attrib, l2.attrib;

The limit of shown data could be the GROUP BY clause and the amount of fields with different data you want to see.

Comment: I would've posted the query but I'm on the Stack Exchange app now. But I do have it posted in my last question on stack overflow.